# Sparkle Effect with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need to Know if it is possible to create a sparkle effect with JQuery 'n CSS. In addition a Tutorial would be really helpful.

I need to apply this effect on an image. Though if it is possible to produce such effect in general, please show me how and I will apply it by myself.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by a sparkle effect.

I assume you want something like a moving highlight effect on your image.

My first port of call would be to have two variants of your image. One, a static one with no 'sparkle' and the other an animated GIF with your sparkle effect added. Then, when you want to display your sparkle effect (such as during mouse over), simply switch the images.